# What are the best methods to fetch data from DB in Real time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

How to update database and fetch updates in DB in real time?

I have tried some on the internet. I have found that I can use [socket.io](https://socket.io/), but I am not sure this will be the most effective procedure. I am hoping to use javascript languages. Also I have found that Angular and Firebase will do the job. but I want to use my own database.

Any idea?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For real time CRUD operations with DB better to use cloud databases, Firebase, AWS dynamoDB are better choices because they are scalable according to your need. You can make use of MongoDB also, you've to configure it with Nodejs & write simple API to read & write data in database. It works really great & easy to implement. Follow some sample of MEAN stack app. (Mean.io) Again there's cloud version of MongoDB also available (mlab.com) to host your database.

Comment: So that means DB to client real time action I have to use $watch ?

Comment: Yeah exactly and $apply after that to make those changes app level. Using cloud database is just like using a web service api. Integrating firebase for Angular/Ionic app is lot easier & good support from firebase team